# reading an entire line including spaces using c

Tags: c

I am trying to read an entire line from the user including white space, however my code right now does the scanf correctly only on the first iteration of the for loop. After that it simply prints x 9 times rather than asking the user again for more input. It is as if the scanf doesn't get called on the subsequent iterations Why is this? How can I fix this? My code is below. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char x[1024];
    for (int n=0; n<10; n++){
        scanf("%[^\n]s",x);
        printf("x = %s\n",x);
    }
```

Comment: Note: A buffer 100 characters long is going to overflow.

Comment: why, i'm not typing that many characters in, only about a dozen

Comment: In this narrow use case, sure. A more reasonable default of 1024 doesn't hurt anything and avoids "What, why?!" type bugs.

Comment: ok, good point, I'll change that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf("%[^\n]s",x)` reads in everything except a `\n`. This means that after the first read, it will leave the `\n` in the buffer, such that every consecutive read will not read in anything (that's why `x` remains as is).

For reading in lines (i.e. having a correct treatment of the `\n`), `fgets` is usually much better suited. And when you want to get rid of the `\n`-character (which will be part of the string read in by `fgets`), you can use the `strcspn`-function:

```
int main(){
    char x[1024];
    for (int n=0; n<10; n++){
        if (!fgets(x,1024,stdin)) {
           break;
        }
        x[strcspn(x,"\n")]='\0';
        printf("x = %s\n",x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Be sure to check if `fgets` succeeds.

Answer (score 7):

[The `scanf` family has myriad problems](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) including leaving items in the buffer which it will then continue to re-read. That's what's happening to you. If you don't need to use it, don't use it.

Use `fgets` to read whole lines. Then if you want to parse the line further use `sscanf`.

```
char line[BUFSIZ];
while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL ) {
    ...
}
```